# Symbol issue in Python

Tags: python, teradata

i have an issue with symbols using Python.
I connected Teradata to Python with teradatasql extension.
Inside my tables, I have some texts with the "€" symbol, but when I extract the data from that table, the symbol doesn't appear.
Any suggestion?

```
with teradatasql.connect([my connexion]) as con:
    with con.cursor() as cur:
        for table in list:
            cur.execute("select * from mydb."+table+";")
            for row in cur.fetchall():
                [HERE I PRINT THE DATA]
```

Comment: Probably an encoding problem. Easiest is to ensure that UTF-8 is used everywhere.

Comment: My database is UTF-8 and the file where I write my data is also encoded on UTF-8
sqlFile = open("INSERT TABLE "+table, "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8")

Comment: Does your terminal decode the output from your Python code as UTF-8?

Comment: @chepner I'm using Visual Studio Code, how can I check that?

Comment: Have you try to run it in terminal or cmd?

Comment: sadly. it doesn't matter where I execute it...

Comment: Is the column in the table defined with CHARACTER SET LATIN or UNICODE? Use the CHAR2HEXINT function to check the actual stored character encoding. For server LATIN the Euro sign should be x'FF' or for UNICODE it should be x'20AC'. If it's something else, then the data was loaded incorrectly (e.g. Windows-1252 uses x'80' for this character; if that value is loaded using default ASCII session character set the value stored will be x'80' for LATIN column or x'00A0' for UNICODE column).

Answer (score 0):

The teradatasql driver always uses the UTF8 session character set, but you must properly configure your console window in order to display Unicode characters.

Use Windows Command Prompt. Press Alt+Space to open the window menu. Choose the Properties item from the menu. On the Font tab, set the window font to SimSun-ExtB.

That font is needed in order to display all Unicode characters.

Execute the command: `chcp 65001`

This changes the console window to the UTF-8 code page, which will enable Python to print Unicode characters to the console window.

Finally, run your Python script that executes a query using the teradatasql driver. Query results containing Unicode characters should be printed properly.

Comment: What if I want to write the data into a file? I'm using VSCode to run my pyhton

Answer (score 0):

Use the UTF-8 encoding to write UTF-8 data to a file:

```
import io
with io.open('euro.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write('\u20ac\n')
```